# JS/jQuery Dynamically Replace each/multiple IMG on page using thumbnail image from API

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vimeo

I'm struggling to write the proper function to replace each img instance inside the wrapper div's. The page I'll be implementing this on will have a dynamic number of wrappers with thumbnails and Vimeo links. I'm trying to dynamically apply the thumbnail, by pulling it from the API, to each img instance accordingly.

Here is a styled page for reference where the first instance works correctly: https://rapt3.webflow.io/projects/tbe-banner-video-22

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/gatesweeney/pen/oNdLjMa) with the latest snippet.

```js
var ele = '#wrap';

    $.each($(ele), function()
    {
        var vimeoLink = $("a#vimLink").attr("href");
        var vAPIprefix = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=";
        var url = vAPIprefix + vimeoLink;
        var vURL;
        var img_url;



        $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        img_url = data.thumbnail_url;
        console.log(`IMG URL: ${img_url}`);
        jQuery('#titleID').replaceWith(img_url);
        $('#thumb').attr("srcset",img_url);

        });

    });
```

```css
.wrapper {display: flexbox; flex-direction: column;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="wrap" class="wrapper">
<div id="titleID">Test</div>
<a id="vimLink" href="https://vimeo.com/566613630">View on Vimeo</a>
<img id="thumb" src="">
</div>

<div id="wrap" class="wrapper">
<div id="titleID">Test</div>
<a id="vimLink" href="https://vimeo.com/747740403/7c08c6505a">View on Vimeo</a>
<img id="thumb" src="">
</div>

<div id="wrap" class="wrapper">
<div id="titleID">Test</div>
<a id="vimLink" href="https://vimeo.com/747740344/d1cc0af377">View on Vimeo</a>
<img id="thumb" src="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved it myself after some help from Kinglish. First change was using classes instead of ID's

> You cannot use the same ID tag more than once. The reason why only the first one works is because it is the first instance of the ID. Instead, use classes. So, loop through the .wrapper and use the find() method to target the elements within each wrapper.

But the other issue was that $.getJSON runs async, causing the replace actions such as `$(this).find('.thumb').attr("src", img_url);` to fail to run. By moving the replace calls outside of the `$.getJSON` AND adding this snippet `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});`, the `$.each` works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same ID tag more than once. The reason why only the first one works is because it is the first instance of the ID. Instead, use classes. So, loop through the `.wrapper` and use the [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to target the elements within each wrapper.

I can't test this, but it should work

```js
var ele = '.wrapper';

$.each($(ele), function() {
  var vimeoLink = $(this).find("a.vimLink").attr("href");
  var vAPIprefix = "https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=";
  var url = vAPIprefix + vimeoLink;
  var vURL;
  var img_url;

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    img_url = data.thumbnail_url;
    console.log(`IMG URL: ${img_url}`);
    $(this).find('.titleID').html(img_url);
    $(this).find('.thumb').attr("src", img_url);

  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flexbox;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="titleID">Test</div>
  <a class="vimLink" href="https://vimeo.com/566613630">View on Vimeo</a>
  <img class="thumb" src="">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="titleID">Test</div>
  <a class="vimLink" href="https://vimeo.com/747740403/7c08c6505a">View on Vimeo</a>
  <img class="thumb" src="">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="titleID">Test</div>
  <a class="vimLink" href="https://vimeo.com/747740344/d1cc0af377">View on Vimeo</a>
  <img class="thumb" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: Its successfully pulling each thumbnail URL now according to console, but the replace functions are not working. Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I meant to update that - just did. I assume you just want to show the URL in the title area? Then you can just set it as such `$(this).find('.titleID').html(img_url);`

Comment: Correct, but the main thing I need to replace is the img srcset="", and thats not working apparently

Comment: Ok, you can set srcset (but you'll need more info in there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) , but you definitely need `src` as well `$(this).find('.thumb').attr("src", img_url);`

Comment: For some reason its still not setting those attributes. src, srcset, or the div text. I'll add my snippet again in a reply below